# assert is not evaluated in return ()

Tags: haskell, assert

I have the following code snippet, where [assert](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.13.0.0/docs/GHC-Base.html#v:assert) is used to check an invariant regarding some internal state. However, `assert` is never evaluated and thus never fails even when it should, probably because `return` is not evaluated when returning type `()`. This holds even if I change to `assert False`. Any way to fix this?

```
FooM :: m () // m is a monad
FooM = do
  state <- get
  // some state mutation
  state' <- get
  return $ assert (state /= state') ()
  return $ assert False () // <-- this also never fails
```

Comment: Please include your actual code. This would never compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return $ assert (state /= state') ()` *is* evaluated, because the monadic `>>=` needs to evaluate it to figure out "what to execute" (it just so happens that that is "nothing"). But though the *action* is evaluated, the *value* `assert (state /= state') ()` contained in that action is not, because it isn't used. The solution is to guard the *action* `return ()` with `assert`, not the (ignored) value `()`.

```
assert (state /= state') $ return ()
```

Alternatively,

```
return $! assert (state /= state') ()
-- = let arg = assert (state /= state') () in arg `seq` return arg
-- for evaluation to "get to" the return, the assertion must succeed
```

Comment: The first way is much cleaner than the second, unless you need `$!` there anyway.